# Xamarin - Connect to Mac

Tags: xamarin, visual-studio-2015, xamarin.ios, xcode8

When developing with Visual Studio 2015, is it possible to use a Mac for both iPhone and Android builds?

A virtual machine would cope with Windows and Visual Studio.
The host system is an Apple Mac.
So can I connect from the virtual machine to the host system concerning Xamarin? (like 2 different computers, which is frequently stated in Xamarin tutorials)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Windows in a Virtual Machine on the Mac to run Visual Studio is possible. You would be able to connect to the build host on the host machine and build your iOS project.

However, you can also just run everything on the Mac and rely on Xamarin Studio or Visual Studio for Mac to build both iOS and Android.